# Don't have to cast segue destination view controller anymore?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I saw this in a codebase:

```
BlablaViewController *bbVC = segue.destinationViewController;
```

I thought this always needed to be casted to the correct type. Did something change in Objective-C recently that makes this cast no longer necessary?

Comment: Inferring during compile time by swift may be one of the reason, not sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since xcode 7 you have a new annotation called __kindof which allows you to point with UIViewController subclass (BlablaViewController in your case) to UIViewController. please see this example:
https://happyteamlabs.com/blog/how-to-use-__kindof-in-objective-c/

Comment: So you can assign it to anything that is a subclass of UIViewController and if at run-time it turns out not te be the correct one, it will blow up?